# mambo: email goes to spam

Tags: php, email

I built a site on mambo v 4.5.2 and
under Global Configuration tab -> Mail set PHP mail function option

but if I send email from `abc@hotmail.com` it goes in to SPAM
however if I use `abc@gmail.com` it goes in to Inbox.
There is a screen shot.
[image]
Kindly help me to fix this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of reasons; there is [a good summary](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) up by the SO authors.